# How to store ACF custom fields data in a custom table

Tags: plugins, php, database, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the ACF Custom Fields plugin to store some info, but to my understanding, it is stored in the wp_postmeta table. Is it possible to store it in a custom table instead? So for example, the data would be: fullName, age, gender. and I would like to create a table called personalInformation and have these 3 columns.

Comment: the most efficient way in WordPress to manage a new kind of object is to create a custom post type https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to save ACF data in custom tables by using a separate paid plugin called [ACF Custom Database Tables](https://www.awesomeacf.com/storing-acf-data-custom-database-tables/).

However, if your goal is just to keep the database as light as possible, meevly.com's solution of creating your own custom metaboxes would be the lightest-weight option, versus adding two plugins just to track a few bits of data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free plugin now https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-fields-in-custom-table/.

It was heavily inspired by Austin Ginder's post https://anchor.host/acf-custom-fields-stored-in-custom-table/

Answer (score -4):

Unfortunately, **you can't do that.** In order to store your data in a separate database table, you should manually add custom meta boxes and save the data wherever you want. You can read more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/